# 1:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform, // This heppens whenever i write code rellated with firebase storage

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-test

``` ````` your text`- -  ````<kbd>[tag:your text]</kbd> `````Launching lib\main.dart on 220233L2I in debug mode... Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... lib/retrieve_images.dart:1:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform. import 'dart:html'; ^ Context: The unavailable library 'dart:html' is imported through these packages:`

```
package:white =\> dart:html
```

`Detailed import paths for (some of) the these imports:`

```
package:white/main.dart => package:white/retrieve_images.dart => dart:html
```

`Unhandled exception:`
`FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)`
`#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)`
`#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:654:37)`
`#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:794:21)`
`<asynchronous suspension>`
`#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:629:9)`
`<asynchronous suspension>`
`#4      starter (package:frontend_server/starter.dart:99:12)`
`<asynchronous suspension>`
`#5      main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/x/w/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:13:14)`
`<asynchronous suspension>`

`Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception`

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.`

- `Where:`
  `Script 'C:\Users\91908\Downloads\flutter_windows_3.7.0-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151`
- `What went wrong:`
  `Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.`

> `Process 'command 'C:\Users\91908\Downloads\flutter_windows_3.7.0-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

- `Try:`

> `Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.`
> `Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.`
> `Run with --scan to get full insights.`

- ``` Get more help at ``https://help.gradle.org ```

`BUILD FAILED in 19s`
`` Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1` ``

Comment: Please share your main.dart code

Comment: nothing in the main.dart , i just import firebase storage and and given below

Comment: ElevatedButton(onPressed: ()async{
        final results = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
          allowMultiple: true,
          type: FileType.custom,
          allowedExtensions: ["png","jpg"],
          allowCompression: true
        );
        if(results == null){
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("no file selected"),));
          return;
        }
        final path = results.files.single.path;
        final filename = results.files.single.name;

        storage.uploadFile(path!, filename).then((value) => print("done"));

Comment: if you are imported  dart:html  remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The file where you imported firebase storage, you'll see a html package imported, get rid of that and import material.dart and try, that worked for me.